# Action on each element of an inline list

Tags: c#, .net, iterator, collections

I'm trying to learn the "functional" part of C#/.Net for work, and I'm not sure if this is a good way to write this statement.
I was also trying to reduce duplicated code while not introducing too many allocs. From my understanding everything created by **new** here will be flagged for release once the **.ForEach()** is finished. Or the compiler optimizes the **new**s out.

```
enum Fruits {Apple, Banana, Pear, Peach, Orange, Lychee}

new List<Fruits>
    {
        Fruits.Apple, Fruits.Banana, Fruits.Orange, Fruits.Lychee
    }
    .ForEach(x => Eat(x));
```

Just to note. I'm aware I could have written it the **foreach loop** way aswell

```
foreach (var x in new List<Fruits>{Fruits.Apple, Fruits.Banana, Fruits.Orange, Fruits.Lychee})
{
    Eat(x);
}
```

Comment: You're worried about things that should only worry you in extreme situations: https://stackify.com/premature-optimization-evil/ . First and foremost write readable code, and only if you are encountering (significant) performance issues, start optimizing code.

Answer (score 5):

I can see only a single `new` there so it doesn't really matter in this context. If you have code that creates millions of them I suggest asking a new question with the actual code. As far as this one is concerned you'll fine with a single line where you let `Enum` grab all the values and pass `Eat` to the `Select` without the lambda as its signature matches the lambda.

```cs
var results = Enum.GetValues<Fruits>().Select(Eat);
```